# How to transform the key and value of a each entry set of a Map using Java 8?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, String>` that I want to transform to a `Map<Type1,Type2>` using Java streams.

This is what I tried but I think I am getting the syntax wrong:

```
myMap.entrySet()
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> Type1::new Type1(e.getKey()), e -> Type2::new Type2(e.getValue))));
```

Also tried

```
myMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(new Type1(Map.Entry::getKey), new Type2(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

But I just keep running compile errors. How do I do this transform?

Comment: Is it necessary to use streams? Often times, it's easiest to start with the plain code and then use streams if you want to simplify it. For your task, you would want to call map() after stream(). Streams and lambda functions are a pain because typing is vague to the user. That's my warning. Good luck. And one ref that is in the right direction... https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/

Comment: Your syntax for `collect` and `Collectors.toMap` is correct. I tried the similar code with this collect:  `Map<Integer, Integer> x = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getKey()), e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue())));`. It works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like what you really want is

```
 myMap.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         e -> new Type1(e.getKey()), e -> new Type2(e.getValue())));
```

though I admit it's honestly difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
     .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(new Type1(entry.getKey()), new Type2(entry.getValue()))
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html

Or more elegantly:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
     .map(this::getEntry)
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

private Map.Entry<Type1, Type2> getEntry(Map.Entry<String, String> entry) { 
     return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(new Type1(entry.getKey()), new Type2(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Since when is there a no-arg `toMap` collector?

Comment: There is. If I have to do some logic on data and then collect it to map, I prefer to map it first and then collect it.

Comment: Maybe, the problem stems from looking into the Java 7 API when dealing with Java 8 specific code. There, you won’t even find `Collectors`. When using the Java 8 API reference, you’ll notice that [there is no `Collectors.toMap()` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collectors.html)…

Comment: After reading documentation - you are right. I obiously use it long ago. Thanks - I'll correct my answer

Comment: To be fair, it would be very useful if there was one and it wouldn’t be so hard to provide it, i.e. as `public static <K,V> Collector<Map.Entry<K,V>,?,Map<K,V>> toMap() { return Collectors .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue); }`…

Comment: Note that your edited code contains a mistake. Since `getEntry` return the most abstract type `Map.Entry`, you can’t use functions referring to `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` in `toMap`, even if you know that the instances will have that actual type. In this case, correctly using `Map.Entry` instead, makes the code even shorter. There is no reason to ever refer to the concrete type `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` outside the `new` expression.